# PDF con PHP y SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, fpdf

Hola Buen día por primera vez estoy haciendo un pdf desde una tabla pero no me sale
quise hacerlo de esta manera con este código

```
     <div>
    <div style="width: -10%; float:right">
  <button id="imprimir" class="btn btn-info">Imprimir</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.print/1.6.0/jQuery.print.min.js" integrity="sha256-s/wuIT+s0uE5Igk30VS2UAcs5Ck6SDt+iTlUzYQBn/4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('#imprimir').click(function() {
            $.print('#imprimible');
         
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

**RESULTADO**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como se puede observar si imprime lo que quiero nada mas que sale con los botones entonces decidi hacerlo manualmente por medio de la libreria FPDF pero en la consulta me sale error
esto es lo que llevo de código en el PDF**

```
  <?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Cabecera de página
function Header()
{
    // Logo

  //IMAGE (RUTA,X,Y,ANCHO,ALTO,EXTEN)
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Movernos a la derecha
    $this->Cell(90);
    // Título
    $this->Cell(90,12, utf8_decode('Hoja de Costos'),1,5,'C');
    // Salto de línea
    $this->Ln(25);
}

// Pie de página
function Footer()
{
    // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
    $this->SetY(-15);
    // Arial italic 8
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
    // Número de página
 //   $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Página ').$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

include '../includes/db.php';
$folio_hoja= $_GET['folio_hoja']; 
$emp_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT  * FROM hoja_costos
                                        where folio_hoja='$folio_hoja' ");
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($emp_query);

 
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

while($row=$row->fetch_assoc()){
    $pdf->Cell(10,10,$row['cantidad'],1,0,'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(10,10, $row['descripcion'],1,0,'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(10,10,$row['precio_refac'],1,0,'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(10,10,$row['total_refac'],1,0,'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(10,10, $row['mano_obra'],1,0,'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(10,10,$row['importe_total'],1,0,'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(10,10,$row['proveedor'],1,1,'C', 0);
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

**ESTE ES EL CÓDIGO DE LA VENTANA DONDE QUIERO QUE SALGA EL PDF**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->
</head>
<?php 
//activamos almacenamiento en el buffer
ob_start();
require 'header.php'; 
 ?>

<style>
    
    .panel .form-group{
        margin:unset;
   
    }


  .columna {
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  
  .columna {
    width:auto;
    float:none;
  }
  
  * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#columna1 {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  font-size: 12px;
  
}
#columna2 {
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  font-size: 12px;
 
}

#columna3 {
  width:70%;
  float:right;
  font-size: 12px;
 
}


}


</style>

<div class="col-md-12">
<?php 
include '../includes/db.php';
$folio_hoja= $_GET['folio_hoja']; 
$emp_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT  * FROM hoja_costos
                                        where folio_hoja='$folio_hoja' ");
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($emp_query);

 ?>
</div> 
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Default box -->

<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
  <br>  

    
    
        <div class="panel-body"> 
        <div class="col-md-13">
        <center>    
    <label class="control-label" style="font-size:25px !important">Detalle Hoja de Costos</label>
    </center>

  <br>  
  
<form action="orden_entrada.php" method="get" align="right">
    <input type="submit"  value="Regresar" 
         name="Submit" class="btn btn-md btn-info" />
</form>
<br>    
  
<hr style="border-bottom:1px solid black"></hr>
</div>  


    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row form-group">



    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row form-group" id="columna1">
        <label class="control-label">Folio:</label>
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $row['folio_hoja'] ?></label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row form-group" id="columna1">
        <label class="control-label">Fecha:</label>
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $row['fecha'] ?></label>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group" id="columna1">
        <label class="control-label">VIN:</label>
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $row['VIN'] ?></label>
    </div>

    
    </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="row form-group" id="columna2">
        <label class="control-label">Placas:</label>
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $row['placas'] ?></label>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-group" id="columna2">
        <label class="control-label">KMS:</label>
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $row['kms']?></label>
    </div>
 
    <div class="row form-group" id="columna2">
        <label class="control-label">Factura:</label>
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $row['factura']?></label>
    </div>
 
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  </div>
  </div>
  
    <!-- COMIENZO TABLA -->


<table id="hoja" class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>

      <tr id="heads">
      <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Cantidad</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Descripción</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Precio Unitario Refacciones</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Importe total Refacciones</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Mano de Obra</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Importe Total</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Proveedor</th>
        <th class="col-md-1 text-center"></th>
    
        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    
    include '../includes/db.php';
    $folio_hoja=$_GET['folio_hoja'];

      $query=  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM hoja_costos where folio_hoja='$folio_hoja'");
         
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {   
        
    ?>
      <tr>

      <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['cantidad']  ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['descripcion']  ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['precio_refac'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['total_refac'] ?></td> 
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['mano_obra'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['importe_total'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['proveedor'] ?></td>
        <td style="text-transform:capitalize" class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" a href="#costos<?php echo $row['ID']?>" data-toggle="modal" a title="Editar" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>    </td>
       </tr>
 
       
      <?php 
include '../includes/hoja_update.php';

    };
      ?>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
        <!-- FIN TABLA -->


<table id="hoja" class="table" >
    <thead >
      <tr id="heads">
        <th class="col-md-3" ></th>
        <th class="col-md-4"></th>
        <th class="col-md-4"></th>
        <th class="col-md"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>

    <td >   
    <a class=" btn btn-md btn-info"  href="#cost" data-toggle="modal"><center> Agregar </center></a>

</td>
<?php
    
    include '../includes/db.php';
    $folio_hoja=$_GET['folio_hoja'];

      $query=  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(importe_total) as sumtotal FROM hoja_costos where folio_hoja='$folio_hoja'");         
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        $output=$row['sumtotal'];
       
    ?>
<td >   
<center> <div >
<h4>
       <label class="control-label">Total:</label>
        <FONT COLOR="TEAL"> <b> <?php echo $output?> </FONT></h4>  
    </div> </center> 
</td>

<td >  

    <div>
    <div style="width: -10%; float:right">
  <button id="imprimir" class="btn btn-info">Imprimir</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.print/1.6.0/jQuery.print.min.js" integrity="sha256-s/wuIT+s0uE5Igk30VS2UAcs5Ck6SDt+iTlUzYQBn/4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $('#imprimir').click(function() {
            $.print('#imprimible');
         
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
</div></td>

<td>  

</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>

</table>

       
    
        


</div>
  </div>
  </div>

<div id="cost" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog"> 
               <div class="modal-content modal-md">  
             
                  <div class="modal-header"> 
                     <h4 class="modal-title" id='head'>
                     <center>   <i class=""></i> Nuevo Hoja de Costos </center>
                     </h4> 
                 
                  </div> 
                  <form method="POST" id='hoja_form'  > 
 <div class="modal-body">
           
 <div class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label"> Folio:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" id="folio_hoja" name="folio_hoja" type="text"   placeholder="INGRESE EL FOLIO" required>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Cantidad:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase"  autocomplete="off" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" type="text"  maxlength="4" placeholder="Ingrese la cantidad" >
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Descripción:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase"  autocomplete="off" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese la descripción" >
        </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Precio Unitario Refaccciones:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase"  autocomplete="off" id="precio_refac" name="precio_refac" type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese el Precio Unitario" >
        </div>
        </div>
             
        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Mano de Obra:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase"  autocomplete="off" id="mano_obra" name="mano_obra" type="text"  value=0 >
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="form-login">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Proveedor:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input class="form-control" style="text-transform: uppercase"  autocomplete="off" id="proveedor" name="proveedor" type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese el Proveedor" >
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btn_sub">Guardar</button>
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-close"></i>Cancelar</button>
</form>
                     </div>
                     </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
        

        </div>
        
        </div>
 


        </div>

  
  </div>

 
  
  
 </section>
    


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        jQuery("#hoja_form").submit(function(e){
                                e.preventDefault();
                                var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "../forms/add_hoja.php?action=hoja",
                                    data: formData,
                                    success: function(html){
                                        $('#retCode1').html(html);
                                    var delay = 2000;
                                        setTimeout(function(){  window.location = "detalle_hoja.php?folio_hoja=<?php echo $folio_hoja?>"; }, delay);  
                                    
                                    }
                                });
                                    return false;
                        });
                        });
</script>


    <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Version 2.0</b> 
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2023 Todo los derechos reservados.
  </footer>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**QUISIERA SABER SI ME PODRIAN AYUDAR DE FAVOR COMO HACER EL PDF DEL CODIGO QUE LES MOSTRE **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo desde el cliente, si quieres. Basta con poner una clase y en el `.css` una [@media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@media) `print` para indicar aquellos elementos que no quieres imprimir.

En este ejemplo, ponemos la clase `notPrint` al botón y a una de las imágenes, lo cual hará que esos elementos sean ignorados al momento de imprimir.

Usaremos además el método [`Window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/print), sin necesidad de usar librerías de terceros.

```css
@media print {
  .notPrint {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="notPrint" onClick="window.print();">Imprimir</button>
<hr class="notPrint" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit mus, <b>auctor felis tortor aliquam ridiculus aptent hendrerit</b>, sagittis curabitur scelerisque sed at donec nostra. Nascetur odio sociosqu facilisis donec quisque nisl cum cursus, himenaeos aliquet sodales magna feugiat faucibus lobortis ac, dui leo sapien ullamcorper nibh lacinia lacus. Lobortis pellentesque himenaeos ac velit mattis luctus quisque, tempus vel rutrum varius tellus non iaculis, nascetur taciti primis ad dictumst dapibus.</p>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9yWS.png" alt="Esta imagen se imprimirá">
<p>Nam tortor id facilisis sodales quis dapibus sapien vulputate tincidunt sagittis mus congue at class, himenaeos leo tristique massa aliquet egestas consequat orci facilisi convallis scelerisque penatibus cum. Proin augue ligula enim nisl blandit nec mus orci, justo porta sem mollis himenaeos metus cras quis, eget nostra aliquet sodales per elementum libero. Duis dui morbi sagittis massa integer inceptos tellus varius hendrerit, parturient dictumst primis cursus ante lacinia risus penatibus porta, fames suspendisse per hac class nisi molestie praesent.</p>
<img class="notPrint" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XBNN.png" alt="Esta imagen no se imprimirá">
```

Si de todos modos te decides por hacerlo con FPDF, dado que en el servidor controlarás el contenido que enviarás como salida del PDF final, simplemente ignora en ese flujo de salida aquellos elementos que no quieres aparezcan en el PDF.

Comment: Excelente, me ayudo mucho tu aportacion muchas muchas gracias